# Apple Mail shows plain text instead of HTML email

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have a gmail account setup as IMAP in Apple Mail and recently some new emails coming through have displayed the plain text version instead of HTML. If I check the same email through gmail.com it shows the HTML fine but back in Mail I can't even change it to HTML under View -> Message -> Next Alternative.

This solution did not work for me:
defaults write com.apple.mail PreferPlainText -bool FALSE

I'm running Apple Mail 5.2 on Mac OS 10.7.3

I have just found that the same email message will show HTML when viewed in the All Mail Folder but not when viewed in the Inbox.

Comment: I use the same setup (IMAP, Mail.app, GMail) but don't have this problem. Can you post the Raw Headers of an example email that shows up plain in Mail but HTML in GMail?

Comment: Have you done View > Message > Raw Source in Mail and verified that the incoming messages where this happens actually do include the html version when they get to your machine?

Comment: @Avry I'm only seeing this with some emails e.g. ebay and amazon. The key part of the headers:
Mime-Version:  1.0
 Content-Type:  multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_161163_12044293.1335349020081"

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes, and they do.

Comment: I experience the same issue in Mail 6.0 on 10.8. Any progress on figuring this out thus far?

Comment: This is very strange: When I view the raw source for such a message, it appears to have no headers! So it seems that some how messages get corrupted after the first time they're viewed (in which the html is always rendered correctly)

Comment: And for some reason you consider displaying plain text over HTML a bug rather than a feature? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I opened `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist` in Xcode and searched for `PreferPlainText`.  It seems to want either YES or NO as a value.

I set it to NO and saved, then relaunched Mail.app.

HTML (Rich Text) mail is back.

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution for this but not a reason on why it happens.
To solve the problem, you must delete the ".OfflineCache" folder found in "User/Library/Mail/V2/IMAP-{youremail}/".

Note the folder is hidden (even Library is hidden), so you'll need to use this terminal command to show hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

You'll need to restart the Finder to make the command work, by the way.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: If you're using Terminal, you might as well just `rm -rf ~/Library/Mail/V2/IMAP-{youremail}`.

Answer (score -1):

I just hit rebuild in the "Message" drop down menu and it solved it for me